# XWPFTableRow adding new Row with current style?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I try to use Apache POI to add new row onto the existing XWPFTable such that the row added is hold the style (font, color, etc.) of the last row. Normally, XWPFTable.createRow() returns a row with blank style. I tried to create new XWPFTableRow object using the last row's CTRow as construction parameter and XWPFTable.addRow(). However, when I created the object, it simply reference the last row (whatever change is made to the object is reflected upon the last row, not the newly added one).

How do I get around with this?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but maybe this is useful to someone:

```
xwpfTable.addRow( xwpfTable.getRow( xwpfTable.getRows().size() - 1 ) );
```

Adds a new row at the end of the table, identical to the last row.

Comment: This adds a new row, but the object is the same

Answer (score 1):

```
XWPFTableRow lastTableRow = xwpfTable.getRows().get( xwpfTable.getRows().size() - 1 );
XWPFTableRow row = xwpfTable.createRow( );
for ( List< String > rowData : rowList )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < rowData.size(); i++ )
    {
        XWPFTableCell cell = row.getCell( i );
        XWPFTableCell prevRowCell = lastTableRow.getCell( i );
        if( cell != null )
        {
            cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcBorders();
                        cell.getCTTc().getTcPr().setTcBorders(
                                           prevRowCell.getCTTc().getTcPr().getTcBorders() );
            cell.setText( rowData.get( i ) );
        }
    }
}
```