# How to add a new row with the same style but different object refrence

Tags: object, apache-poi, xwpf

I have this table that I want to add a number of rows to it, if I used this method `table.addRow(rowInTable);` the data later will be inserted in the same row. I researched about it and the method does add a row but it gives the new row the same object as the old row.

I have seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166042/7153098 but I want a better way to work with this problem.
tried to create a new row object but didn't work

`XWPFTableRow newRow = new XWPFTableRow(rowInTable.getCtRow(), table);`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211749/cant-change-row-text-in-docx-file-once-row-is-added-to-table/53246880#53246880.

Comment: so in the ```insertNewTableRow``` you have added the row but then you needed to re-assign table rows' indexes so you did it in ```commitTableRows```? why didn't the table do it by itself since you added a row in similar approach to ```XWPFTable.createRun();```?

Comment: I don't know why and I told this in my answer too. The `commitTableRows` is a workaround only.

Comment: oh okay thought you knew why since a year was passed, thank you for the help